# Open File Security Warning at boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, security, administrator, reboot

Every time I boot my laptop I get this annoying message.
I trust this program and I want it to run on-boot without prompting me with this annoying message.

Even if I unchecked "Always ask before opening this file" and clicked Run, It will still ask me the next time I open the program.

I'm on the only account on the laptop and It's an Administrator account

Any help is welcome

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unblock the file:

- Right click the program
- Click Properties
- In the General tab, click the `Unblock` button